# How to use LIKE for an Inet column?

Tags: postgresql

I have a column in my database called mgmt which is an inet type

I would like to do this:

```
select * from source
where mgmt LIKE inet('10.208.6%')
```

but this gives the error "ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type inet:"

Any idea how I can use the LIKE clause for an inet type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First idea:

Casting into text and try then:

```
WHERE mgmt::text LIKE '10.208.6%'
```

---

Second idea:

Try this

```
WHERE mgmt BETWEEN inet('10.208.60.0') AND inet('10.208.69.255')
```

(or, even more precise, because your wildcard covers both, `6` and `60`s)

```
WHERE (mgmt BETWEEN inet('10.208.60.0') AND inet('10.208.69.255'))
    OR (mgmt BETWEEN inet('10.208.6.0') AND inet('10.208.6.255'))
```

---

Third idea:

If you just want to check the `6` range, use the [`<<` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-net.html) to check the IP range:

```
WHERE mgmt << inet('10.208.6/24')
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `<<` operator to do `inet` operations:

```
postgres=# SELECT '192.168.1.1'::inet << '192.168.1.0/24'::inet;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT '192.168.10.1'::inet << '192.168.1.0/24'::inet;
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

But if you really must use `ILIKE` for some reason, you can cast to text:

```
postgres=# SELECT text('192.168.10.1'::inet) ilike '192.168.1%';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

More information can be found in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-net.html)